# R ggplot: add a regression line with a fraction of the data, defined by a condition on a different column on the source dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say we have this dataframe:

```
    one<- rep(c("a","b","c"),each=5)
    two <-(1:15)
    three<-c(1,2,3,4, 2,4,6,8,10,12,14, 3,6,9,12)
    df<-data.frame(one,two,three)
```

and we create a scatter plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=two, y=three)) + geom_point()
```

And say we suspect that there is some hidden information in the scatterplot that would become clear if we overlay three regression lines on the scatter plots, for the different categories of column one. How to do that?

Stack Overflow deleted my original question, referring me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195314/geom-smooth-on-a-subset-of-data)

However, the inclusion condition in that example is on the x data itself (not referring to another column). And when I try to follow it:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=two, y=three)) + geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(data=df$two[df$one == "a"], method='lm',formula=y~x,se=F)
```

I get an error:

Error in subset.default(df, x = df$two[df$one == "a"]) :
'subset' must be logical

Is there a way to do it? It seems there should be, given that the data are taken from the source data frame.

Comment: Try e.g. `geom_smooth(aes(color = one),  method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE)` to get a regression line for each category of `one`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=two, y=three)) +
 geom_point() +
 geom_smooth(aes(color = one), method='lm', formula = y~x, se = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We could use `geom_smooth()` with subsets of the data:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = two, y = three, color=one)) +
  geom_point(size = 2)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("a"="blue", "b"= "red", "c" = "green"))+
  geom_smooth(data = subset(df, one == "a"), method = 'lm', formula = y ~ x, se = F) +
  geom_smooth(data = subset(df, one == "b"), method = 'lm', formula = y ~ x, se = F) +
  geom_smooth(data = subset(df, one == "c"), method = 'lm', formula = y ~ x, se = F) +
  labs(color = "Category") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]